# SUMIF with "ISNA" condition and for duplicate entries & for multiple criteria

Tags: excel

Solutions request for SUMIF for formula which is working for sumif for model qty sum with duplicate entries.

Now, I'd like the formula to SUM the qty against each model (multiple entries) as above BUT with condition for each country.

I am assuming that IF condition at the beginning would somehow give me solution but it returns error.

Here's the link to the file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0aOVjxZjuyrOXkzN2RzbXlJTDg

[SUMIF formula example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKyYH.png)

below is the formula I am currently using.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A:A, Inventory!A:C, 4, 0)), "0", SUMIF(Inventory!A:A, Master!A3, Inventory!C:C))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like COUNTIF(s) in your last question when you add criteria you need to swithc to SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(Inventory!C:C,Inventory!A:A,$A3,Inventory!B:B,B$1)
```

Put this in B3 and copy over and down.

Comment: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A:A,Inventory!A:C,4,0)),"0",SUMIFS(Inventory!C:C,Inventory!A:A,$A3,Inventory!B:B,B$1))

Comment: You can get rid of the IF and VLOOKUP.  The VLOOKUP is wrong and will always throw and error.  It is not needed.  If nothing satisfies the criteria of the SUMIFS() it will return 0 on its own.

Comment: @NFS63 Basically only use the formula without anything else that I gave as the answer.

Comment: @NFS63 remember if this answered your question please mark it as such.  You should also go back and mark the correct answers to your previous questions.  I noticed a few that were not marked as such.

Comment: I am testing this one and shall mark that when satisfied.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. One last thing, If I wanted to bring "0" as a result of no value, what would be the change. Currently it is showing "-"

Comment: @NFS63 you have a format on those cells that is turning the `0` into `-`.  Change the format to "General" and the `0` will reappear.

Comment: Thanks. Your support is much appreciated.